# Can I build the environment variable through the strings and numbers concatenation?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file

Windows 7; Building C++ project through the command line.

I have installed Visual Studio 2005-2015. Therefore I have the set of the environment variables: `VS80COMNTOOLS`, `VS90COMNTOOLS`, `VS100COMNTOOLS`, `VS110COMNTOOLS`, `VS120COMNTOOLS`, `VS140COMNTOOLS`:

[image]

In my `autorun.bat` I use such calling:

```
call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %1
```

But I want to point the visual studio tools version through parameter too:

```
set vs_tools=VS%1COMNTOOLS
call "%%vs_tools%%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %2
```

But this is the incorrect record. How can I do it?

Comment: I guess the shortest code would be `call set vs_tools=%%VS%1COMNTOOLS%%`

Comment: thank you, your variant works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't directly `call %%variable%%`, it works only as `call CMDcommand %%variable%%` by passing the original `%%` as `%` into the command context where `%%var%%` becomes `%var%` and normal variable expansion occurs.

   ```dos
   call set vs_tools=%%VS%1COMNTOOLS%%
   call "%vs_tools%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %2
   ```

   The first command sets `vs_tools` via `call` trick.
   The second command uses normal `%variable%` expansion to run the batch file.
2. Another method is to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

   ```dos
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
   call "!VS%1COMNTOOLS!..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %2
   ```